# How to access HTML input element on javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to retrieve the customers name by alert based on the account number that's entered into the textbox by i'm having trouble referencing the textbox (>>txtFree<<). I just not sure what i must replace it with if anyone could help please.

**HTML**

```
Account Number: <input type="text" id="txtFreeBank" name="txtFreeBank" />
```

**JS**

```
function checkBankAc() {
        var txtFree = parseFloat(document.getElementById('txtFreeBank').value);

        var bankdetails = Parse.Object.extend("BankDetails");
        var query = new Parse.Query(bankdetails);
        query.equalTo("AccountNum", >>txtFree<<);
        query.find({
            success: function (results) {
                alert("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " scores.");

                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    var object = results[i];
                    alert(object.id + ' - ' + object.get('CustomerName'));
                }
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you log `txtFree`? Does it get the desired value?

Comment: Not sure if i'm even doing that 100% right but it returns the value I enter?

Comment: That's what I meant. Are you using `query.equalTo("AccountNum", >>txtFree<<);` or `query.equalTo("AccountNum", txtFree);`?

Comment: No, sorry for the confusion i'm using txtFree, i just used that to emphasize that I don't know what I need to replace >>txtFree<< with.

Comment: are you attaching this javascript inside the <script> html tag? How are you calling the javascript?

Comment: yeah, they're in the script tags and its being called by onClick()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be able to access the data entered switching your `>>txtFree<<` for the following:

```
document.getElementById('txtFreeBank').value
```

Comment: Thank you ... i was just missing the .value